# Override a service for another service in angular (hierarchical injector)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have put a service (service1) in the providers array of app.module.ts. Let's say I have 2 more services, service2 and service3, and both of these require service1 to be injected in them. Service2 is fine with the instance of service1 provided app wide (by app module's provider array), but service3 wants a new instance.
In case of components, we can simply add service1 in providers array of the component for which we want a fresh instance, how to achieve the same in case of services?

Comment: Sorry I don't see your point. Please, provide the code you have. A service is always meant to exist only once. It's a Singleton. By injecting a service you share it among all injectors. But you do not create a new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all I would review your logic, since this use-case feels awkward at best - but we can't advice on that without further explanation from your side. Perhaps you would be better off with having two services deriving from the same abstract class?

If you did rethink your design and this is what you need - this is doable, but comes with some implications.

In your module (or whatever provider that provides Service1) you can have two providers for the same class, e.g.

```
providers: [
  { provide: Service1 },
  { provide: 'service1new', useFactory: () => new Service1() }
],
```

Of course you can add dependencies to the factory if needed be:

```
providers: [
  { provide: ServiceZ },
  { provide: Service1 },
  { provide: 'service1new', useFactory: (z: ServiceZ) => new Service1(z), deps: [ServiceZ] }
],
```

Then your `Service2` can inject the singleton:

```
//Service2
constructor(private readonly service1: Service1) {
  ...
}
```

And in your `Service3` you can inject new instance each time it's instantiated by specifying other provider:

```
//Service3
constructor(@Inject('service1new') private readonly service1: Service1) {
  ...
}
```